# How Can I Create New Google Maps Markers Using JSON Data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, axios

Sorry to bother. I'd like to use data from an Airtable database to output new markers in a Google Map. I am fairly new to this all, so apologies in advance for my ignorance.

So far, I am pulling in the data from the database using the axios library. I can access the coordinates. However, I am struggling to iterate over the JSON object and then create a Latitude and Longitude object from each object to save as parameters for the map marker. Theoretically, this should be very simple. However, as I said, I only have a basic understanding of JavaScript, as I am afraid that I am only a hobbyist rather than a professional.

The code I am using is as follows:

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
  });
}

// Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
// set of coordinates.

function getAirtableData() {
axios.get("https://api.airtable.com/v0/apptDNPo9jnXShzNh/Map%20Test?view=Grid%20view",
    {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer keyOfJOed1eMhUOGH" }
    }
  ).then(function(response) {
      console.log("Got data (showing first record): ", response.data.records[0]);
      const lattitudeData = [];
      const longitudeData = [];
      //Get an array of records for the 'Lattitude' field
      response.data.records.forEach(function(item){
        lattitudeData.push(item.fields.Lattitude);
        longitudeData.push(item.fields.Longitude);
        console.log(lattitudeData);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: lattitudeData, lng: longitudeData});
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latLng,
       map: map
      });
      });

    });
  }


  getAirtableData();
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js">
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAHZQkAh_lv36EuNhPlLTxZvdZQUMIkEo0&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you see the first record in the console? If so, the only issue I can see is that you have two arrays but aren't using them properly. Remove all the array parts and simply do `....LatLng({
        lng: item.fields.Lattitude,
        lat: item.fields.Longitude
      });` (I swapped the coordinates because one location had a latitude smaller than -90) Here's a working fiddle that uses `fetch()` to get the JSON data: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/s1ex6oL2/

Comment: (Also, you either have a JSON String *or* an Object, there's no such thing as a JSON object)

Comment: Hi Chris G, thanks very much for taking the time to explain. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry for also actually getting the coordinate data wrong too... Oops.